# set ivars from NSDictionnary

Tags: objective-c, ivar

I'm currently working on a project where the user defines some parameters in a NSDictionnary, that I'm using to setup some objects.
For example, you can ask to create a Sound object with parameters param1=xxx, param2=yyy, gain=3.5 ... Then an Enemi object with parameters speed=10, active=YES, name=zzz ...

```
{
active = NO;
looping = YES;
soundList = "FINAL_PSS_imoverhere_all";
speed = 100.0;
```

}

I then instantiate my classes, and would like to set the ivars automatically from this dictionnary. 
I've actually wrote some code to check that this parameter exists, but I'm having trouble in actually setting the parameter value, especially when the parameter is non object (float or bool).

Here's what I'm doing so far :

```
    //aKey is the name of the ivar 
    for (NSString *aKey in [properties allKeys]){
        //create the name of the setter function from the key (parameter -> setParameter)
        NSString *setterName = [aKey stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0,1) withString:[[aKey substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString]];
        setterName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"set%@:",setterName];
        SEL setterSelector =  NSSelectorFromString(setterName);
        //Check if the parameter exists
        if ([pge_object respondsToSelector:setterSelector]){
            //TODO : automatically set the parameter
        }
        else{
            [[PSMessagesChecker sharedInstance]logMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cannot find %@ on %@", aKey, [dict objectForKey:@"type"]] inColor:@"red"];
            NSLog(@"Cannot find %@ on %@", aKey, [dict objectForKey:@"type"]);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I don't know what to do once I've found that the parameter exists on the object. I tried to use "performSelector... withObject..., but my problem is that some of the parameters are non-objects (float or bool).
I also tried to get the class of the parameter, by using the setter, but it didn't help.

Did anyone manage to do something like that?

Comment: `setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:`!

Comment: Oh! I missed that one! 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Jack Lawrence's comment is spot on.
What you are looking for is called **Key Value Coding**, or just **KVC**.
This fundamental part of Cocoa lets you get and set any instance variable using its name as a String and a new value.

It will automatically handle coercing Objects to primitive values, so you can use it for int and float properties too.

There is also support for validating values and handling unknown properties.

[see the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html)

your code, without validation, could be written

```
for( id eachKey in props ) {
    [anOb setValue:props[eachKey] forKey:eachKey];
}
```

or just

```
[anOb setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:props];
```

as Jack said.

Comment: Yep, what I'm doing is that I'm keeping my validation loop (as the dictionnary contains additional informations I don't want to parse), and create an other dictionnary in the line where I've got the TODO comment. I'm then using that new dictionnary with setValuesForKeysWithDictionary
Works like a charm !

Answer (score 0):

For the non-object parameters you have to put them into an object, for example `NSNumber` or `NSValue`. You can then add these objects into your dictionary.

For Example:

```
float f = 0.5;
NSNumber f_obj = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:f];
```